# Css3 @fontface is not working with Chrome 17 and Firefox 10

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying this code For the @fontface for an arabic font :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MothnnaFont';
src: url('fonts/mothnna.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('fonts/mothnna.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('fonts/mothnna.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('fonts/mothnna.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('fonts/mothnna.svg#svgMothnnaFont') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I'm using the font in a class named demo :

```
.demo
{
    font-family:'MothnnaFont',Sans-Serif;
    width:800px;
    margin:10px auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:10px;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

This code is working on ie but it's not working on firefox 10 or chrome 17

Here is a demo http://tmr.hyperphp.com/font/demo.html

Here is how the font should look like

[image]

So anybody can help me to make this font appear a cross all browsers ?

**Solved:** just downloaded the font and converted it again and it's all working now 
thank you all for helping

Comment: Perhaps the use of two `src:`? Try `,` instead of `;src:`.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Everything else looks like it's about right.

Comment: I know these are basic questions but do you have a doctype and is the encoding set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax of embedding web-fonts is not bulletproof anymore.
Try using the Fontspring syntax instead:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MothnnaFont';
    src: url('fonts/mothnna.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/mothnna.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/mothnna.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/mothnna.svg#svgMothnnaFont') format('svg');
}
```

It's just the first double appearance of the "src"-attribute you have to fix.

This will solve your problem.

For more information about the syntax, take a look at this [source](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax). And by the way, fontsquirrel is also using this syntax as its default.