# persian font not applied in android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, webview

I have html content (combined Persian an English text) with attached css, all css style applied correctly but font.

The css have fontface like this:

```
@font-face{
        font-family: 'BYekan';
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url(../Fonts/BYekan.ttf); 
    }
```

**the font only applied to english text and not the persian**. the font is a standard **ttf** persian font (BYekan.ttf) so nothings wrong with it.

I googled a lot and almost every body said it's a bug in `WebView` android > 3.0, the problem still exist in android 4.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38536
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/persian-computing/4Fm7JfiOkJk

The only workaround that I found is using **svg** fonts instead, but this **does not work for me** either.
[Custom font for webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032829/custom-font-for-webview)

**So how can I solve this?**

**note1**: this question probobly asked alot, like this:
[Persian @font-face doesn't work in Chrome, Bug or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970001/persian-font-face-doesnt-work-in-chrome-bug-or-not)
but it's an old question and the given advice not working anymore (at least for me).

**note2**: When I open the page in chrome desktop browser font applied correctly.

Comment: *when i open the page in chrome desktop browser font applied correctly.* means ?

Comment: means all text shown in specific font face, i mean nothong is wrong with html or css.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the workaround

try these font faces

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yekan’;
src:url('fonts/yekan.eot?#’) format(‘eot’),    
      url('fonts/yekan.woff') format('woff'),
      url(‘fonts/yekan.ttf’) format(‘truetype’); 
}
```

IMO use [SVG font](http://jeremie.patonnier.net/post/2011/02/07/Why-are-SVG-Fonts-so-different) for persian language

Comment: the `css` you mentioned didn't work, in the original question i mentioned that `svg` font tested and did't work either (i converted the `ttf` to `svg` via online tool, may something went wrong, i don't know).

Answer (score 0):

I've converted the mentioned font in your question and uploaded it in the following Internet address:

[bYekan Web Font Package](http://www.files.com/shared/5407107606f1d/bYekan.zip)

Also, You must use the following Style Lines:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BYekan';
    src: url('../Fonts/byekan-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../Fonts/byekan-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../Fonts/byekan-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../Fonts/byekan-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../Fonts/byekan-webfont.svg#BYekan') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and, you should add the following lines in the **.htaccess** file:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```